# observable value is a part of another observable

Tags: angular, typescript

*indexData* and *indexEditData* are the observables i used in my application. *indexData* holds a json object. I used this json values to build a table. I done editing in that table rows by selecting the rows. On selection, the json of the selected row  to be edited will be placed in indexEditData.  Within this variable i have to done changes in values. When i change values, it reflects in the indexData observable too.

How can i restrict that change? I dont want to change values in indexData while i am editing in indexEditData.

```
private INDEX_DATA: any[] = [];
private indexDataSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.INDEX_DATA);
indexData = this.indexDataSource.asObservable();

private INDEX_EDIT_DATA: any[] = []; // For Grid in edit view 
private indexDataEditSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.INDEX_EDIT_DATA);
indexEditData = this.indexDataEditSource.asObservable();
```

Answer (score 0):

indexData is observable but you don't need indexEditData as observable because it will be just a local component's state.

I suggest you should:

- declare `indexData` as `observable (ReplaySubject)`, `indexEditData` just normal array of objects
- get data from your source and store in `indexData`. Subscribe to it and store the value in `indexEditData`
- use `indexEditData` for update/editing etc
- once editing is finish, replace the `indexData` value using `indexData.next(indexEditData)`

Hope this resolve your issue.

Comment: index table and edit table are in two components, indexComponent and indexEditComponent. I created this observables in a service.

Comment: That's fine. indexData can be passed as observable to edit component. You can retrieve the value (as subscribe to it) and use it locally into another variable. Once editing is done, you can trigger back an event from edit component to main component and pass back the edited data.